# 2014 VW Touran 1.6TDI 1T3 UK Windscreen Washer Motor Fuse

Tags: vw, fuse, fuse-panel

I'm trying to find the fuse for my windscreen washer pump motor on my right-hand-drive, but the manual states that the fuse schedule is not available at time of print.  The Haynes manual shows only the fuses for the left-hand-drive, and neither the mirror image or the number map.

Answer (score 3):

A quick search for "2014 VW Touran fuse location" provided a [rather comprehensive link](https://fusesdiagram.com/volkswagen/fuses-and-relay-volkswagen-touran.html). All photos from linked site:

There's a photo of the fuse box under the left side of the dash:

[image: Fuse Box location]

A diagram of the fuse numbering:

[image: fuse numbering]

and a listing indicating that a fifteen amp fuse belongs in location F32 for the windscreen washers.

Yeah, the fuse numbering image is lacking, but I'd expect to see something on the cover to be a bit easier to read.

Comment: Thanks, but according to that site, it would be F32 or F53, but both those number are blanks on my car.

Answer (score 0):

On closer inspection of the Haynes manual, when I found the correct table for my vehicle year, although the fuse layout is paritally mirroed on my UK car, going by the numbers, it's a 20A fuse at F29.

[image]

Comment: I was hoping that the circumstances allowed for mirroring.

Comment: The washer pump may be wired to run from the windshield wiper circuit. If wipers run, find the washer pump and wiring. Examine it for damage and/or corrosion to the electrical connections. Disconnect wiring to the pump and measure it for 12vdc; with ignition ON engine OFF and someone activating the washer pump. If the wipers run in wash mode, see if wipers can be lifted off the windshield and stay upright. Either power is measured on one pin and/or ground is corroded/damaged/missing. The pump should run as it tends to last beyond the life of most vehicles. Either wiring or pump failed.